# PHP $ special character escape

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I have this PHP script I am using to generate an iMacro script and I am unsure how to enter new lines and escape the '$' that is in the string which is a code from iMacro.

PHP keeps thinking that '$' is part of PHP in

```
"TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:win0divUW_CO_JOBTITLE_HL$"
```

How can I do new line in PHP and get PHP to take the $ as a string.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$file = 'datagenerated.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);


for ($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++) {

for ($i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++) {
 $current.="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:win0divUW_CO_JOBTITLE_HL$" +$i+ " EXTRACT=TXT\n";
}
$current.="TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$img$0\n";

}

$current.="SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Documents\iMacro FILE=Names.csv";

file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

For some reason this is the output after escaping using \$

```
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$0
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Documents\iMacro FILE=Names.csv0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VWzhdownzimgz0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VWzhdownzimgz0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VWzhdownzimgz0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VWzhdownzimgz0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VWzhdownzimgz0
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\HuKham\Documents\iMacro FILE=Names.csv0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$0
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Documents\iMacro FILE=Names.csv0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$img$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$img$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$img$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$img$0
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$img$0
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Documents\iMacro FILE=Names.csv
```

Comment: You sure you want to use `+$i+` and not `.$i.`? This isn't JS.

Comment: You're right that was the 2nd problem I was having! Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the `$` with the escape character `\`:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++) {

for ($i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++) {
 $current.="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:win0divUW_CO_JOBTITLE_HL\$" .$i. " EXTRACT=TXT\n";
}
$current.="TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW\$hdown\$img$0\n";

}
```

You could also use single quotes but then you would need to  move your new line characters outside of the single quotes or else they would taken as a liter `\` and `n`:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++) {

for ($i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++) {
 $current.='TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:win0divUW_CO_JOBTITLE_HL$' .$i. ' EXTRACT=TXT'."\n";
}
$current.='TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:win0 ATTR=NAME:UW_CO_JOBRES_VW$hdown$img$0'."\n";

}
```

---

Plus, I've noticed you're using `+$i+` instead of concatenating `.$i.` which have been changed to reflect it.

Comment: You commented as I added that to my answer :)

Comment: I've never seen this type of syntax before `+$i+`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's because that would be an error! I fixed it in my code and hopefully the question-asker will do the same in theirs.

Comment: I've noticed you did it for the first one, but not the second. May I have the honors? ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would be honored it if you edited my post :)

Comment: There, how's that? ;-)

Comment: Much better. Thank you for tidying up. Ironically that's what I'm doing around my home right now....

Comment: You're quite welcome John. Anything to help out. Tonight's pretty weird, the skies are getting meaner and meaner, not too "molto bene", if you know what I mean.

Comment: @JohnConde something weird is happening in the output file: the counter values are appearing one after another but they were suppose to be in between the strings to make a new line...Look at my updated output.

Comment: Uh-oh. Did we break something John?

Comment: Sure sounds like it. Let's see if we can fix that, too.

Comment: Ohhhh well will ya lookah dat, we did "fix" it after all! Nothing broken; that's good.